# Parse datetime when it comes in two different formats - Python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, python-dateutil

Depending on whether the item is over a week old or not, the date comes in the following formats:

Less than a week old comprised of day of the week and time:

```
date1 = "Monday 21:14"
```

More than a week old, is just the date:

```
date2 = "5 Apr '21"
```

I read them in as a string and need to parse them both to a consistent timestamp.

One way I tried is:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse(date1)
# output: datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 23, 22, 18)
parse(date2)
# output: datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 5, 0, 0)
```

Using the `dateutil` package I can get it to easily parse `date2`, but it gives me the forward looking friday for `date1` not the previous friday.

How would you suggest I parse the two dates, without knowing which will be received? and can I instruct the parser to take the last previous weekday (i.e. previous friday)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a default for the parser might work. Since you want *to take the last previous weekday* in case the day of the month is not defined, you can use today's date one week ago.

Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import parser

date1 = "Monday 21:14"
date2 = "5 Apr '21"

# reference = date of today one week ago (as datetime object):
ref_date = datetime(*datetime.now().timetuple()[:3]) - timedelta(7)

for d in (date1, date2):
    print(parser.parse(d, default=ref_date))
    
# 2021-04-12 21:14:00
# 2021-04-05 00:00:00
```

Note that today is Monday 2021-4-19 but this code gives you the *previous* Monday, 2021-4-12.